# Как найти одинаковые элементы, во всех файлах и записать их в новый файл?

Tags: python

У меня есть например 5 файлов txt и там записано вот так:
`[2, 47, 11, , 79, 71, 51, 74, 56, 97, 44, 67, 64, 73, 8, 80, 41, 15, 80]`
но в каждом файле разные значения

мое задание найти одинаковые элементы, которые содержаться во всех файлах и записать их в файл под названием result.txt

мой уже написанный код:

```
import os
from random import randint

os.mkdir('files')

dgtxt = randint(1, 10)
name = 0

for i in range(dgtxt):
    c = randint(1, 1000)
    list_1 = [randint(1, 100) for a in range(c)]
    name += 1
    with open(f'files/file_{name}.txt', 'w+') as fl:
        fl.writelines(str(list_1))
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Counter

Comment: Код не относится к заданию. Начни делать задание,  потом приходи с конкретными вопросами.

Answer (score 1):

```
files = ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt', 'file_3.txt']
(s, *lst) = (f.read().strip()[1:-1].split(', ') for f in map(open, files))
s = set(s)
for a in lst:
    s = s.intersection(a)
with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(sorted(s)))
```

Comment: а если например файлов 5?

Comment: в files имена файлов добавить

Comment: а в моем коде, создается рандомное количество файлов

Comment: да какая разница, хоть 100500, просто разберитесь что тут делается

Comment: Можете сделать os.walk по папке с файлами, если их неизвестное количество

Comment: @VladYerko *У меня есть например 5 файлов txt*